# How to ignore changes in WordPress cache files in Git?

Tags: wordpress, git, themes

Every time I make a change to one of the WordPress theme files for my site there will be a lot of deleted cache files that automatically follow. Should I commit these changes using Git also or just ignore them? If the latter, what is the proper code I would use for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont use wordpress, but if you are looking to ignore them you should have a file called .gitignore, and you are going to want to add those files (or if they are all in a folder, the folder) to the .gitignore file. https://github.com/DragonToothSoftware/SLang/blob/lexer-mod/.gitignore here is what mine looks like. It eliminates all of the cmake cache files

Answer (score 0):

You should use a .gitignore file to exclude these files. They are auto-generated, so no need to keep them in repository